# Preferences like TableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, three20

I am currently working on an internal settings menu for my app (I know the global one for all application settings).
For the Menu I am using the Three20 lib.

My question: Is there a table cell for Three20 TTTableViewController which looks like the cells in the global preferences menu? What I need is a cell with a caption on the left side, the value on the right side and also a accessory item on the right side. I didn't find anything like that.

Another thing is, that the built-in table cells in the Three20 lib won't display any accessory item. I also set the value for the "URL" propert to something like "tt://blablabla" and I am reacting on the url forwardings, but the accessory items aren't displayed.

Thanks for your help!

C YA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found the solution on my own. I am now using the [InAppSettingsKit](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/) for my preferences like menu.

Because I just need the UI of this menu and not it's ability to change the settings, I am just using the TableCell Views in my own UITableViewController. It's working like a charm ;).

Hope this can also help someone around here!

C YA